# My web site is freezing - probably JavaScript, but I can't identify why

Tags: javascript, jquery, freeze

I know this is a long shot, so I'm not counting on an answer, but I just for the life of me can't figure out why this web design keeps freezing my browsers.

http://fuzionve.com/test

I ran the Audit tool in Chrome Developer Tools, but nothing seems that substantial. When I load it in the browser, it freezes, then loads completely at once.

Any suggestions?

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me. Firefox 19.0.2 on win7.

Comment: Works fine on my Chrome.

Comment: I would move your JavaScript files to the bottom of the document and not in the head. The network tab shows the blocking nature of the jQuery.js file.

Comment: Works fine on Firefox + Chrome on my Win7...

Comment: This tool also is great https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine here.

Some advice on "easy" optimizations:

1. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic" />` - this is an external stylesheet. Your browser has to set up a connection with another server. Consider downloading the font (and stylesheet) to your own server.
2. You load 4 stylesheets, which requires 4 roundtrips to the server. Consider merging those in 1 stylesheet. If you prefer using multiple stylesheets in development, merge them into a single file in the release version.
3. Same thing for scripts: you have 3 scripts. Consider merging them into 1 file in the release version.
4. When your browser detects a `<script>` element, it stops rendering your page until that script file has been downloaded from your server and executed. This is because scripts can use document.write() to write HTML, changing your page. 
   If you know your scripts don't write HTML (usually they don't, at least until the document.ready event is fired), consider using the HTML5 `async` or `defer` attributes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/script). Note that these attributes are only supported in modern browsers.

If those things don't help, follow Brad M's advice to trace your problem.

Comment: It was actually the PT Sans font, surprisingly. I didn't think it would make that much of an impact, but it was quite substantial. I reanalyzed what I needed and decided not to load the italic version of the font, and it seems to have sped up the site considerably.

I will definitely consider downloading the font as well, but I wasn't entirely sure if that would violate some copyright or something. I'll look at the license.

Answer (score 5):

1) Remove/comment out code

2) Load Page and test if freezing

3) if still freezing, repeat from step 1

4) if not freezing, examine the code you just removed.

Comment: Commenting out chunks of code is a great way to start troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using multiples (and heavy ones) plugins, what you can do, is change some of their codes, to start after another, like callbacks, at least i changed 3-4 plugins codes to make that change.

Its possible accomplish this job, checkinging, with setInterval, to see if some plugin its done.
Or implement a callback, into the code, after he done, call another code.

i've found this lib, which can help you:
https://github.com/caolan/async